# Set VBA code in SAP excel script value based on Excel field (Column)

Tags: excel, vba, scripting, sap-gui

My script is working however there is one field I can't figure out how to change in the VBA script.  I need to change it based on an entry in Excel.

Here is the script where I am experiencing the issue, the value I have bolded (**4**).

I've tested when changing the value manually and it works. But what I need is to change the value (**4**) to different values based on data in the excel file.

Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:1202/tblSAPMV50ATC_LIPS_OVER_INB").getAbsoluteRow(**4**).Selected = False
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:1202/tblSAPMV50ATC_LIPS_OVER_INB/txtLIPS-POSNR[0,**4**]").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:1202/tblSAPMV50ATC_LIPS_OVER_INB/txtLIPS-POSNR[0,**4**]").caretPosition = 0

Example:
If Excel file says "20" in column G, then change above (**4**) to (**1**)
So simply put, replace the value in the script based on excel value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, you need a `case` statement. I'd do it like this:

```
Select Case value = test_condition

   Case condition_1
      rowResult = 1

   Case condition_2
      rowResult = 2

   ...

   Case condition_n
      result_n

 [ Case Else
      result_else ]

End Select
```

Then SAP code would be:

```
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:1202/tblSAPMV50ATC_LIPS_OVER_INB").getAbsoluteRow(rowResult).Selected = False
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:1202/tblSAPMV50ATC_LIPS_OVER_INB/txtLIPS-POSNR[0," & CStr(rowResult) & "]").SetFocus
Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV50A:1202/tblSAPMV50ATC_LIPS_OVER_INB/txtLIPS-POSNR[0," & CStr(rowResult) & "]").caretPosition = 0
```

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the excel file. 
https://imgur.com/a/w0AnY 
Forgive my ignorance but what would I put in in exactly as I am very new to all of this?  Each line runs then repeats for the next line.  So Column G is "40" the script needs to have 3.   Next line is "30" so script needs to run as 2 (and so on)

Comment: @Skavis can't access your picture at work. But everything is in my answer, your condition 1 is for instance 40, and the rowResult is 3. Gl